# Does Linux .so functions have independent stack of share the stack with the caller?

Tags: linux, stack, shared-libraries

It is known each thread has independent stack but what about functions in <strike>static</strike> shared object in linux system?

Comment: Functions run on the stack of the thread that calls them.

Comment: `.so` files are *shared* objects, not *static* ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both static (.a) and shared (.so) libraries use the stack of whoever calls them.